# Is it possible to deploy multiple Azure resources in a single azapi_resource?

Tags: azure, terraform, azapi

My employer's Azure estate is heavily policied, which results in complications when trying to provisioning infrastructure with the AzureRM Terraform provider. For example, the **Azure Key Vaults should use private link** policy makes it impossible to provision Key Vaults without a private link assigned. However, creating a private link requires the target resource to already exist. This results in a catch-22 situation where both resources must be deployed simultaneously. Our current workaround is to deploy both resources at the same time via an ARM template deployment using `azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment`.

We are gradually trying to replace all usages of `azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment` with the azapi provider.
Is it possible to deploy multiple Azure resources in a single `azapi_resource` resource in the azapi provider?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to deploy within a single provider. you can use [`depends_on`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/depends_on) block to specify the order in which resources are created.

I tried using `depends_on` to create a sample workspace and container applications environment using the `azapi` provider, and it worked as intended.

**`main.tf`:**

```bash
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azapi = {
      source = "Azure/azapi"
      version = "1.7.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "azurerm"{
features{}
}
provider "azapi"{}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
  name     = "ksdnf-rg-rg"
  location = "eastus"
}
 
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "main" {
  name                = "newest-la"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 90
}
resource "azapi_resource" "containerapp_environment" {
  type      = "Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments@2022-03-01"
  name      = "conajshacae"
  parent_id = azurerm_resource_group.main.id
  location  = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
 
  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      appLogsConfiguration = {
        destination = "log-analytics"
        logAnalyticsConfiguration = {
          customerId = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.main.workspace_id
        }
      }
    }
  })
  depends_on = [
    azapi_resource.containerapp_environment
  ]
}
```

*Initialized*  `terraform init` *and validated the configuration with* `terraform plan`:

[image]

*Executed* `terraform plan`:

[image]

*Created successfully using* `terraform apply`:

[image]

*Deployed in Portal:*

[image]

[Reference article](https://thomasthornton.cloud/2022/08/31/deploying-multiple-container-apps-in-azure-using-terraform-and-azapi/) by @Thomas Thornton for more relevant information.

*Note:* In some scenarios, it would be a specific behavior of the `azapi` provider you specified if it permits installing multiple Azure resources within a single `azapi_resource` block. In such cases, I would recommend you use `AzureRM` providers to avoid any conflicts.

Comment: Hi @Jahnavi, thanks for trying to help me out :).  Your response doesn't answer my question though unfortunately because you've deployed three Azure resources using three  different Terraform resource blocks.  The reference article that you link to is close to doing what I want to do; in this article the author deploys multiple `Microsoft.App/containerapps` resources in Azure from a single `azapi_resource`, but I'd like to deploy multiple resources of different types from a single `azapi_resource` resource, as you can with `azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment`.